# Playing audio with setInterval in ts/js & electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron, howler.js

I'm creating a metronome in electron, playing the audio using howler.

While the window is on screen, the audio plays like it should be but when I minimize the window, the audio starts to play in wrong interval and the metronome fails.

these are the audios that I use to play the beats

```
const mainBeat = new Howl({
  src: ["sounds/Boutique808.mp3"],
  onplayerror: (e) => console.log(e),
});
const secondBeat = new Howl({
  src: ["sounds/tick.mp3"],
  onplayerror: (e) => console.log(e),
});
```

startBeats function creates an interval calculated by the function bpmToMs, if the bpm is 60 then the results is 750ms

the function playBeat plays the mainBeat if the currentBeat is 1 or 0 else plays the second beat

```
startBeats = (..._: any[]) => {
   this.setState({ playing: true });
   this.playBeat();
   this.beatInterval = setInterval(() => {
     this.playBeat();
   }, bpmToMs(this.state.currentBpm));
};

playBeat = () => {
   this.incrementBeat();
   if (this.state.currentBeat === 1 || this.state.currentBeat === 0)
     mainBeat.play();
   else secondBeat.play();
};
```

I've copied the necessary lines from my react class component so no worries about the unexpected alone syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding **backgroundThrottling: false** in electron webPreferences

```
mainWindow = new MainWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    minWidth: width,
    minHeight: height - 300,
    maxWidth: width,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      backgroundThrottling: false,
    },
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "assets/icons/png/1204x1024.png"),
  });
```

Now it works perfectly fine!